# How do I show different images based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am working on a school assessment, where my goal is to be able to select an image and show that image on a grid based on which grid cell is clicked.

I have mostly been trying to fix my issue with different variations on the `getElementsByClassName` tag to change the source of the image shown in the cell. Currently, I have an array of the source of every different Image, and changing it using a function. Storing the images in html would not be an option for me because I would have to store all 23 images 9 times, but I have not managed to get it to work in CSS either. Previously, I had my images inside *divs* but I thought that it would work better if I attempted to change the background image tag but that didn't work either.

```html
<div id="crafting-table">
        <div class="craft-grid 1" onclick="gridclick(1)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 2" onclick="gridclick(2)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 3" onclick="gridclick(3)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 4" onclick="gridclick(4)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 5" onclick="gridclick(5)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 6" onclick="gridclick(6)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 7" onclick="gridclick(7)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 8" onclick="gridclick(8)"></div>
        <div class="craft-grid 9" onclick="gridclick(9)"></div>
    </div>
```

```
function clickitem(itemnum) {
    "use strict";
    selected_item = itemnum;
}
function gridclick(gridpos) {
    "use strict";
    document.getElementsByClassName("grid-img " + gridpos).style.backgroundImage = images[selected_item];  
}
```

My main issue is that my images just won't show up. No error messages in console just nothing.

Comment: I don't see any class named "grid-img" in the html.

Comment: You can also store the images in the css as background image attribute of class but you will have to set the width and height property.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` only works for a single class.

If you want to you multiple classes try `document.querySelectorAll('.craft-grid,.1')`

--
But I recommend you to do this instead:

```js
function gridclick(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = el.style.backgroundColor == "red" ? "" : "red"; //clicked element style
    console.log(el.getAttribute('data-something')); // data attribute
    console.log([...el.parentElement.children].indexOf(el)); // index of the element relative to the parent
}
```

```css
.craft-grid{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="crafting-table">
  <div class="craft-grid" data-something="first" onclick="gridclick(this)">1</div>
  <div class="craft-grid" data-something="second" onclick="gridclick(this)">2</div>
</div>
```

Use the element as reference is enough. If you want the element to have some data use the data attribute.